# removing the first character in a combination of strings and commands/tokens using \gobblechar of stringstrings

Tags: stringstrings

I'm working with the stringstrings package. It has a command called `\gobblechar` which removes the first character in a string or token. Kindly see my MWE below. it has been revised as per inputs from @egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\gobblechar[q]{Normal Text and \textbf{Bold Text} and \textit{Italic Text} and math commands like $a_{\text{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$}
\edef\myAnyString{\thestring}
\myAnyString
\end{document}
```

I'm expecting my argument to `\gobblechar` to be a combination of strings and commands, where the first character is alphabetic.

in the MWE above, the argument is

```
Normal Text and \textbf{Bold Text} and \textit{Italic Text} and math commands like `$a_{\text{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$
```

and the first character, ''N'', is alphabetic. I'm trying to output the same argument but without the first character.

Thus, my expected output is

> ormal Text and **Bold Text** and *Italic Text* and math commands like $a_{\text{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$.

Note that there is no problem if the argument were a pure string. for example, if the argument is ''Normal Text'', the output of the MWE above is ''ormal Text''. The problem, I believe, is when the argument is a combination of strings and commands.

Kindly seeking your help how to achieve this. Im beginning to think the problem is not so simple as it looks.

Comment: the argument may come from book or article titles which may contain both pure strings and commands

Comment: i forgot, i should include \usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: Why are you gobbling? Are you perhaps wanting to do some case changing?

Comment: @JosephWright yes, i wanted to separate my amsrefs content and publisher house styles, like that of apa7th edition. amsrefs bibliography will print it as is. but in case a different style is needed, like that of apa (or another style) which converts everything to lowercase, what i would want is for some capitalized texts in the title to remain capitalized eventhough everything else was lowercased. this makes sense and is more accurate. i have tried numerouse built in commands, to no avail, or i guess i still have to learn a lot from TeX/LaTeX

Comment: once i have gobbled, and obtained the new text, i can just apply a lowercasing command to it. the capitalized portions in the text will not be affected by the lowercasing commands since these capitalized texts were \MakeUppercase'd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an X-Y question. Anyway, you can use `expl3` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gobblefirst}{m}
 {
  \tl_tail:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\gobblefirst{Normal Text and \textbf{Bold Text} and \textit{Italic Text} 
  and math commands like $a_{\mathrm{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi @egreg, thank you! i will try this solution of yours. may i just ask what expl3 is.

Comment: hi @egreg, your solution worked! may i know what an X-Y question is? thank you

Comment: @beethovengg14 An X-Y issue is where you ask something (X) but really need to solve something else (Y)

Comment: just realized expl3 is Wrapper package for experimental LaTeX3

Comment: @JosephWright oh ok. i think it's the same in my line of work in math and engg. you have to solve some big problem (Y), but actually you can solve it by just solving a smaller problem (X). thank you sir

Comment: hi sir @egreg, i have posted a new question, "Preserving the mixed-case of a word within a set of words that was previously set in title case", https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606307/preserving-the-mixed-case-of-a-word-within-a-set-of-words-that-was-previously-se

kindly seeking your help

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for `expl3`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ExplTitlecase}{m}
 {
  \text_titlecase:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplTitlecase{Normal Text and \textbf{Bold Text} and \textit{Italic Text} 
  and math commands like $a_{\mathrm{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$}
  
\ExplTitlecase{normal Text and \textbf{Bold Text} and \textit{Italic Text} 
  and math commands like $a_{\mathrm{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$}

\ExplTitlecase{$a$ text and \textbf{Bold Text} and \textit{Italic Text} 
  and math commands like $a_{\mathrm{c}}=\frac{v^2}{r}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you sir. i will also try your perspective...

Comment: sir your solution also worked. it employed the straightforward approach. both yours and egreg' solution answered by question. thank you. i gues i need to study this expl3 thing

Comment: just realized expl3 is Wrapper package for experimental LaTeX3

Comment: @beethovengg14 Not really any more: it's just the name of the programming layer developed by the LaTeX team

Comment: hi sir @JosephWright, i have posted a new question, "Preserving the mixed-case of a word within a set of words that was previously set in title case", https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606307/preserving-the-mixed-case-of-a-word-within-a-set-of-words-that-was-previously-se, wherein I used a command you suggested. kindly seeking help