# Preserving the mixed-case of a word within a set of words that was previously set in title case

Tags: expl3, uppercase

In the URL [removing the first character in a combination of strings and commands/tokens using \gobblechar of stringstrings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601801/removing-the-first-character-in-a-combination-of-strings-and-commands-tokens-usi), @JosephWright has suggested the command `\ExplTitlecase` (expl3) to capitalize the first word of a set of words set in lowercase.

In the following MWE, I have used Joseph Wright's `\ExplTitlecase`. I have shown Examples 1 to 4.

```
%MWE
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myMixedCaseCommand}[1]{#1}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ExplTitlecase}{m}
{
\text_titlecase:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
%Example 1
\ExplTitlecase{first word will be capitalized}

%Example 2
\ExplTitlecase{a certain \uppercase{UPPERCASE} acronym within a set of words set in lowercase}

%Example 3
\ExplTitlecase{a certain \lowercase{lowercase} acronym within a set of words set in lowercase}

%Example 4
\ExplTitlecase{a certain \myMixedCaseCommand{MiXeDCaSe} acronym within a set of words set in lowercase}
\end{document}
```

The MWE compiles fine, and the output in Examples 1 to 3 are expected. However, what I would want for Example 4 is to find some kind of command, which I temporarily call `\myMixedCaseCommand`, such that this command preserves the mixed-case nature of the acronym MiXeDCaSe. In the output, MiXeDCaSe was lowercased and became mixedcase. I would want the output to be exactly MiXeDCaSe.

Kindly seeking any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to the list of commands that should not have their argument acted on by the process.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myMixedCaseCommand}{m}{#1}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ExplTitlecase}{m}
 {
  \text_titlecase:n { #1 }
 }
% add \myMixedCaseCommand to the exclusion list
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \myMixedCaseCommand }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%Example 1
\ExplTitlecase{first word will be capitalized}

%Example 2
\ExplTitlecase{a certain \uppercase{UPPERCASE} acronym within a set of words set in lowercase}

%Example 3
\ExplTitlecase{a certain \lowercase{lowercase} acronym within a set of words set in lowercase}

%Example 4
\ExplTitlecase{a certain \myMixedCaseCommand{MiXeDCaSe} acronym within a set of words set in lowercase}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir @egreg. it worked.

Comment: it is an exclusion list. so we can just add any number of commands separated by space or newline that we want excluded?

Comment: @beethovengg14 Yes, you can add any number of *robust* commands.

Comment: thank you. i think im beginning to be interested with this expl3 thing, i just have no reference materials to read now. thanks again

Comment: kindly seeking again your help. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606822/find-if-a-string-exists-within-external-files